# TraceLogProvider - using

Tags: postsharp

I wanted to use TraceLogProvider and below is the code of it. When I try to apply it I'm getting error "Cannot serialize the aspects: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." My Idea is to use TraceLogProvider to write sql commands into log. I also pasted the psproj configuration related to TraceLogProvider.

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(AllowExternalAssemblies = true, Inheritance =   
MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
public class TraceLogProvider : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        yield return new AspectInstance(targetElement, new TraceLog());
    }
}
```

**psproj configuration**

```
<d:TraceLogProvider AttributeTargetAssemblies = "System.Data"
AttributeTargetTypes = "System.Data.Common.DbCommand"   
AttributeTargetMembers ="*">   
</d:TraceLogProvider>
```

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Venu

Comment: Do you get the same error if you apply TraceLog aspect directly without using TraceLogProvider? Basically replacing TraceLogProvider with TraceLog in your psproj.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error from time to time particularly when I rename a project or solution. Uninstalling PostSharp and then re-installing PostSharp seems to fix it.